# Macintosh HD - Data unmounted after deleteing data volume and reinstalling macos onto macintosh hd data disk

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility

I'm attempting to reset my MacBook Pro to factory settings and began by restarting my MacBook and hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I selected **Disk Utility** and saw two options: Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - Data. I deleted the Macintosh HD - Data option by accident then reinstalled macOS Catalina onto Macintosh HD - Data. macOS Catalina could not be installed because a "preboot volume could not be created for a APFS install" and in **Disk Utility** under "disk images" there appeared a new option: InstallESD.

I tried deleting the main disk named "APPLE SSD AP0128J.." as another post advised this but it failed. I then attempted to restart by loading from the startup disk and my MacBook went into a load-up loop. I can enter the Utility page with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> but I have no clue how to proceed. Then my Macintosh HD - Data volume was unmounted so I deleted it again and it reappeared but I have no clue how to proceed.

Edit: Apple said to delete Macintosh HD and reinstall macOS onto Macintosh HD. I attempted it but it said that a preboot volume couldn't be created. Now there are two InstallESD disks now.

Comment: If you deleted Macintosh HD - Data you're done. Once you run the installer you can boot up and you should be good to go. What does Disk Utility show now?

Comment: I deleted hd data then proceeded to install macos onto the HD data disk. Before it could finish it said that it could not create a preboot volume for APFS install